# Blaze template conflict with jQuery.sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have an interesting problem:

My Meteor collection has a sort column. My Blaze template helper sorts the collection before rendering.

This collection draws a set of sortable rows, sorted with `$('rowset').sortable();`.

I have an `onStop` event that then reads the new child layout and does an update to the Meteor collection with new `sort` fields.

The change then triggers the collection re-sort, and re-render of the template.

However, I found that Blaze, trying to be efficient, reads the collection sequence change, and instead of redrawing all of the rows, it re-orders them by doing a diff on the previous order.

Being unaware that jQuery already re-ordered the rows, the new resultant order is wrong until I entirely leave and re-enter that template.

The only solution I have found is to:

> a. Empty the collection,
>
> b. After redraw, re-populate the collection in the new order, forcing a full redraw and subsequent correct sequencing.

The problem with this is that the rows disappear and then reappear, giving a terrible presentation.

---

I'm looking for a better solution, perhaps something that tells Blaze not to try and redraw on update. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using the MongoDB `$sort`?

Comment: The sorted property is a deeply nested array within the object, that has been cooked together by joining several Collections on the client side. Don't think I can do a `$sort` based on that.

Comment: Anything that messes with the DOM elements tha Blaze has created can cause trouble  You can transform the collection, calculate your sorting field as a top-level field and have sortable update that field. You may take a look at the following [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2003) on GitHub.

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea! Now if I use `$sort` to update that field, will it redraw properly or still try to do trickery? I don't know how to circumvent jQuery actually moving DOM elements.

Comment: Well, I am unsure as I never used jQuery sortable with Meteor, but there is a wealth of information in those threads. There is also [this blog post](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/adding-drag-and-drop-sorting-to-lists) which suggests binding a `'sortupdate'` listener. It is not entirely clear to me how you determine your ordering info and what it is, and how do you update it when an item is dropped.

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading a collection from DB, you can disable the reactive behavior when fetching data:`find({},{reactive: false})`

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I do a lot of client-side data cooking, involving the joining of several collections together to come to the template object. I definitely would like it to be reactive. Perhaps this joining on the client-side isn't the best practice, however I don't know a better way to do it.